# Why is this String empty when invoking/marshaling this struct from C# to C-DLL?

Tags: c#, c, dll, interop, marshalling

I got a function like this defined in a C-DLL:

```
int AcquireArchive (char* archiveName, Password* password)
```

The struct Password is defined in the DLL as:

```
typedef struct password {
unsigned char* pPwd;
unsigned long length;
} Password;
```

What I am doing is trying to wrap this function in C# using:

```
[DllImport("name.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "_AcquireArchive@16", 
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int AcquireArchive(
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string archiveName, 
ref Password password
);
```

and:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Password
{ 
    public string pwd;
    public ulong length;
}
```

I call this function by:

```
Password password;
password.pwd = "password";
password.length = (ulong)password.pwd.Length;

int code = AcquireArchive("Archive", ref password);
```

Now the problem is that the returned code signals INVALID PASSWORD, indicating (according to the documentation) a password-length of 0. 
Is it possible the value of password.pwd and/or password.length get lost in the invocation/marshalling process?

Sadly I don't have access to the source-code of the dll.

EDIT: CharSet is now Ansi, TYPO "length", removed  [UnmanagedType.BStr]

Comment: Is the C++ code definitely using Unicode? Because `CharSet.Auto` will assume so on WIndows XP or later.

Comment: It is not an UnmanagedType.BStr, remove that.  CharSet.Auto on the struct is wrong, you must use CharSet.Ansi.

Comment: I think there is an error here : password.lenght <----- you should  correct "lenght"

Comment: @MatthewWatson: OP asks about C, not C++!

Comment: @Olaf Same question applies though - whether its C or C++ doesn't make any difference to how structs are marshalled.

Comment: I applied your hints, but no change. the "lenght"-typo was only in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at least one problem I see:
 in your C Code (length is 32 or 64 bit depending to the DLL):

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned char* pPwd;
  unsigned long length;
} Password;
```

and in your C# code(length is 64 bit):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Password
{ 
    public string pwd;
    public ulong length;
}
```

if it is 64 bit , it is OK.
but if it is 32 bit, you should change your C# `ulong` to `uint` like this:

```
public struct Password
{
    public string pwd;
    public uint length;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: That was indeed the problem! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there any kind of overview-sheet for the compatibilty of datatypes when using InteropServices? This would be great to avoids erros like this

Comment: @sascha-g: for this kind of type compatibility, I'm afraid not. but  for converting managed to unmanaged types see this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal(v=vs.100).aspx